# How to convey "being down to earth"

Tags: translation

So i read an interview translated for korean to english and they said someone was down to earth. This made me curious to what the korea would have said for the translation to be "down to earth".

Does anyone know how to convey the same feeling or an equivalent version of this expression?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might be a translation of "털털하다" which means someone is unpretentious.

Comment: Can you provide a link or transcript of the interview here? Have you tried anything to find out how "down to earth" might be said in Korean?

Answer (score 2):

"down to earth" sounds a bit broad and vague.  Korean adjectives that might be translated to that tend to be a little more contextualized, like whether the person is down to earth in manners, tastes, value system, etc.

Here are some words that come to mind.

- 소박하다 = simple and modest in taste and lifestyle. (not luxurious)
- 털털하다 = easygoing and not particular in manner and taste. (not highbrow; lacks finesse)
- 수수하다 = plain and simple in looks and style. (not flamboyant or luxurious)
- 소탈하다 = open and unassuming in one's values and social interaction. (not fastidious)

So if you're referring to someone's lifestyle, 소박하다 might work best. If you mean how they get along with other people, 소탈하다 would be better. If you're describing someone's manner and taste, 털털하다 might also be a good choice. 수수하다 is most often used about appearance but can be applied to personalities too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it can mean "현실적이다(practical)" or "세상물정에 밝다" depending on the context. Eg: a down-to-earth view of marriage - 결혼의 현실적인 견해/관점. down-to-earth traveling tips -현실적인 여행 정보

Comment: Could you please provide examples or more context?

Comment: a down-to-earth view of marriage - 결혼의 현실적인 견해/관점.  down-to-earth traveling tips -현실적인 여행 정보

Comment: Please add it to your answer. You can edit it in